# Division n items into k boxes prove that it is NP-Complete

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, np-complete

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me with it please? I need to prove that this is a NP-complete problem.

We are given $n$ items with sizes $s_1, s_2, ... ,s_n$, where $0 < s_i < 1$ and a natural number $k > 0$.

Question: Does it exist a division of given items into $k$ boxes if every box has unit size? (The boxes don't have to be fully filled)

Comment: Are we to assume that every object is a cube?  A long, thin pencil may have size $\frac 12$ but it can't be fit into a unit cube.

Comment: @lulu: I would expect each object to be a $1 \times 1 \times s_i$ cuboid so you can ignore all but one of the dimensions

Comment: Well, it's clearly possible if $k \geq n$. If $k < n$, I'm not sure what can be said about the problem in general.

Comment: @Henry You may well be right...certainly that's a sensible assumption.  But I'm not sure it's self-evident.  Maybe the OP can confirm?

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that the problem is NP-Complete or are you asking for an algorithm to solve the problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am asking how to prove that it is NP-Complete. Can I do this by transformation between the Partition and the Bin
Packing Problems?

Comment: @FilipBouška If you're asking how to prove that it's NP-complete, *say that in the question*. That's a different problem than actually solving it.

Comment: Yes, you can reduce Partition to the Bin Packing problem. But first, please change the tag to "NP-Complete".

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).  It is considered computationally hard in general to get an exact answer, but approximate algorithms exist (i.e. ones that find an answer that is provably close to best).

Answer (score 0):

Partition Problem
$\quad$Input: A list L of n integers $i_1,...,i_n$
$\quad$Question: Is there a partition of L into 2 lists, $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $\sum_{i \in L_1}i = \sum_{i \in L_2}i?$

Given an instance of Partition P, create an instance of Bin Packing BP by:

1) Set $k = 2$
2) Set $C = \sum_{i \in L} i$
3) Set $s_j = \frac{2i_j}{C}$

Note that $\sum s_j = 2$

P is a "Yes" instance $\Rightarrow$ BP is a "Yes" instance
$\quad$If there is a partition of L into $L_1$ and $L_2$ then the $s_j$ can be partitioned into 2 lists each
$\quad$summing to $1$. Hence, they can fit into $k=2$   bins.

BP is a "Yes" instance $\Rightarrow$ P is a "Yes" instance
$\quad$If the $s_j$ can be fit into k = 2 bins, since $\sum s_j = 2$, the sum of the $s_j$ in each bin must be equal.
$\quad$Let $L_1$ be a list of $i_j$ corresponding to $s_j$ in one of the bins.
$\quad$Let $L_2$ be a list of $i_j$ corresponding to $s_j$ in the other bin.
$\quad$So, there exists a partition of L into $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $\sum_{i \in L_1}i = \sum_{i \in L_2}i$